# Progress<T> doesn't have Report function

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have windows form app this is my code:

```
  private async void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Progress<string> labelVal = new Progress<string>(a => labelValue.Text = a);
        Progress<int> progressPercentage = new Progress<int>(b => progressBar1.Value = b);

       // MakeActionAsync(labelVal, progressPercentage);
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>MakeActionAsync(labelVal,progressPercentage));
        MessageBox.Show("Action completed");
    }

    private void MakeActionAsync(Progress<string> labelVal, Progress<int> progressPercentage)
    {
            int numberOfIterations=1000;
            for(int i=0;i<numberOfIterations;i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                labelVal.Report(i.ToString());
                progressPercentage.Report(i*100/numberOfIterations+1);
            }
    }
```

I get compilation error that "System.Progress' does not contain a definition for 'Report' and no extension method 'Report' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Progress' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

**but**
If you look at Progress class:

```
public class Progress<T> : IProgress<T>
```

and the interface IProgress has function Report:

```
  public interface IProgress<in T>
{
    // Summary:
    //     Reports a progress update.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   value:
    //     The value of the updated progress.
    void Report(T value);
}
```

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Progress<T>` implemented the method with [explicit interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25585242/2530848). So you can't access the `Report` method with instance of type `Progress<T>`. You need to cast it to `IProgress<T>` to use `Report`.

Just change the declaration to `IProgress<T>`

```
IProgress<int> progressPercentage = new Progress<int>(b => progressBar1.Value = b);
```

Or use a cast

```
((IProgress<int>)progressPercentage).Report(i*100/numberOfIterations+1);
```

I prefer former version, latter is awkward.

Comment: what you mean by "explicit interface implementation" the interface method should not be visible in subclass?

Comment: The reasoning behind this is to encourage your methods to accept an `IProgress` argument rather than `Progress` (eliminates the need for an explicit cast). This allows the caller of your method to provide their own implementation of `IProgress`.

Answer (score 6):

As shown in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that method is implemented using a explicit interface implementation. That means it is hidden if you don't use the interface to access the method.

Explicit interface implementations are used to make some properties and methods visible when referencing to the interface, but not in any derived class. So you only 'see' them when you use `IProgress<T>` as your variable type, but not when using `Progress<T>`.

Try this:

```
((IProgress<string>)progressPercentage).Report(i*100/numberOfIterations+1);
```

Or when you only need to reference properties and methods available in the interface declaration:

```
IProgress<string> progressPercentage = ...;

progressPercentage.Report(i*100/numberOfIterations+1);
```