# Inheriting from an interface with properties of the same name

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an interface IProduct and two partial classes SearchedProductInternal and SearchedProductExternal. 
These two classes are extending classes coming from 3rd party webservice searches but both return slightly different result types.
I want to use the interface for both so they type returned is the same. I know how to inherit but what do I do to return the "Name" as both the interface and SearchedProductInternal have the same object name?

My Interface is similar to as follows:

```
   public interface IProduct
        {  
            string Name { get; }
            string ID { get; }
            string DescriptionShort { get; }
            string DescriptionLong { get; }
         }
```

My Object SearchedProductInternal has the following properties:

```
     string Name; 
     int ObjectIdField;
     string DescriptionShortField;
     string DescriptionLongField;
```

So my this is where I am inheriting

```
  public partial class SearchedProductInternal : IProduct
        {

            public string ID
            {
                get { return ObjectIdField.ToString(); }
            }
            public string Name
            {
                //What do I do here?
            }
            public string DescriptionShort{get { return shortDescriptionField; }
            }

            public string DescriptionLong {get { return longDescriptionField; }
            }
}
```

I want to the return the name that has been originality assigned in the SearchedProductInternal class but I don't know how to do that because if I just put

```
return Name
```

I get a stackoverflow error as it appears to be just keeping calling its self?

Comment: rename the variables of your SearchedProductInternal class

Comment: What Name do you want to call? Is there an explicit implementation of Name in the other Partial class?

Comment: @jehof I cant rename anything in the searched product internal class as this is something I am getting from a 3rd party webservice I am just creating a partial class against it so I can inherit from my interface.

Comment: @MichalCiechan I want to call the name from the OriginalSearchedProductInternal. I am Extending it by making it a partial. Think I'll update my Question to make this clearer

Comment: Extending by making it partial? Unless you are getting the SearchedProductInternal from the 3rd party vendor as a .cs file and compiling it, this will not work, making something partial only tells the compiler to expect more of the class in a different .cs file, it doesn't extend runtime types.

Comment: @RonBeyer Maybe my terminiology is wrong but it working. i have an object called SearchedProductInternal with a load of properties that has been given by my Webservice reference. If I create another partial class called SearchedProductInternal I can add other properties to it or overrride the current ones.

Comment: Yes, it will work *if* you have a SearchedProductInternal.cs file (or file with the class defined) to partial from. . Why not use inheritance and make a new type? I'm not sure how you are doing this because my compiler complains when I try to override partial methods in the same class in two places.

Comment: @RonBeyer I was thinking the same thing, I was sure the compiler does complain if a member has the same name and signature if its a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I just explained this in a way that was not understood but the way that I got this to work was by just using {get;set;}

```
public partial class SearchedProductInternal : IProduct
    {

        public string ID
        {
            get { return ObjectIdField.ToString(); }
        }
        public string Name  {get;set;}

        public string DescriptionShort{get { return shortDescriptionField; }
        }

        public string DescriptionLong {get { return longDescriptionField; }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I think what you should do here is to explicitly implement the interface, so that you will have both your Name property as defined in the class and the IProduct.Name property from your interface.

Comment: Can you give an example. I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: You can have something like:

public partial class SearchedProductInternal : IProduct
        {

            public string Name
            {
                
            }
        
     string IProduct.Name
            {
                
            }            
}

Answer (score 2):

You can [explicitly implement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) the interface, like so:

```
public partial class SearchedProductInternal : IProduct
{
    string IProduct.ID
    {
        get { return ObjectIdField.ToString(); }
    }

    string IProduct.Name
    {
        get { return "Interface name"; }
    }

    string IProduct.DescriptionShort
    {
        get { return shortDescriptionField; }
    }

    string IProduct.DescriptionLong 
    {
        get { return longDescriptionField; }
    }

    // Name property for the class, not the interface
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Class name";  }
    }
}
```

This way you can differentiate between calls to your interface properties and properties with the same name on your class.

When accessing both properties you can also decide which you want, in the following manner:

```
    var test = new SearchedProductInternal();       
    Console.WriteLine(test.Name); // returns "Class name"
    Console.WriteLine((test as IProduct).Name); // returns "Interface name"
```

Comment: You need to omit the access modifier when explicitly implementing an interface.

Answer (score 1):

If your `SearchedProductInternal` already defines the property `Name` and you're trying to return the value of same `Name` property, you don't have to do anything.

Don't create one more property named `Name`. Just get rid of the `Name` property you added. Everything should work because the class already implemented the contract defined by the interface `IProduct`.

If you want to return different value from the `IProduct.Name` property, you can use [explicit interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585188/what-is-it-called-when-you-edit-an-interface/25585242#25585242).

Answer (score 0):

You must change the name of the variable in this case Name.

If that was an ambigous sentence then remember it's the same for the PC. Name cannot be two things. but Name and _Name can.

```
public class SearchedProductInternal : IProduct
{
    string _name = "test";
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
    }
}
public interface IProduct
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer. But a minor issue here, we cannot expose the interface member as public, as it causes compile error.

We can have both class level and interface level members. The interface member cannot be accessed by using class instance, which can be accessed only through interface instance.

```
public interface IProduct
{
    string Name { get; }
    string ID { get; }
    string DescriptionShort { get; }
    string DescriptionLong { get; }
}

public partial class SearchedProductInternal : IProduct
{
    private string _clsName;

    private string _interfaceName;
    private string _objectID;
    private string _shortDesc;
    private string _longDesc;

    public SearchedProductInternal(string _cName, string _iName)
    {
        _clsName = _cName;
        _interfaceName = _iName;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _clsName; }
    }

    string IProduct.Name
    {
        get { return _interfaceName; }
    }

    string IProduct.ID
    {
        get { return _objectID; }
    }

    string IProduct.DescriptionShort
    {
        get { return _shortDesc; }
    }

    string IProduct.DescriptionLong
    {
        get { return _longDesc; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SearchedProductInternal clsSearchProduct = new SearchedProductInternal("clsName", "interfaceName");
        Console.WriteLine(clsSearchProduct.Name);

        IProduct interfaceProduct = (IProduct)clsSearchProduct;
        Console.WriteLine(interfaceProduct.Name);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```